# Put label on a raster map according to latitude

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, raster

```
library(raster)
dat <- getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res=10)
plot(dat$tmin1)
```

[image]

Is there a way to put labels on the above image depending on the latitude. For e.g latitude below -10 has one label, between -10 to 0 has another and so on. Something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting rasters is pretty much like any other base plotting. So you can modify the graphics just like for any other plot:

```
# data
library(raster)
dat <- getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res=10)

# define y locations for labels and lines

y <- seq(-20,20,by = 10)

# plot and suppress y axis (use axes=FALSE if you don't want either)

plot(dat$tmin1,yaxt="n")

# add labels 

axis(2, at=y,labels=sprintf('%s deg. lat.',y), col.axis="darkgreen", las=2)

# add lines

abline(h=y,col='red',lty=2)
```

[image]